# Angularjs assigning dynamic ng-model name ,in constructing elements in list?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, laravel, laravel-blade

Here i defined my code, please help me in this. I am using angularjs in blade template engine of laravel, in this i couldn't dynamically assign name to ng-model in angular

```js
$scope.categoryChange=function(id,model){
     $scope.getCategories(id,model);
        };//category change
        orgusers=0;
        $scope.users = new Array();
        $scope.addUsers = function(){
         if($scope.totalExperts>0){
          orgusers++;
             newUser={"name":"name"+orgusers,"model":"expertise"+orgusers,"category":"empcategory"+orgusers};
             $scope.users.push(newUser);
             if($scope.totalExperts!='' && $scope.totalExperts>0){
              $scope.totalExperts--;
             }
         }else{
          alert("To add users please input total experts field .");
          document.getElementById('focusIt').focus();
         }
        };
        $scope.removeUser = function(removeUser){
         $scope.users.splice($scope.users.indexOf(removeUser),1);
         if($scope.totalExperts!='' || $scope.totalExperts==0){
          $scope.totalExperts++; 
         }
        };
 $scope.getCategories=function(catId,model){
          experts=new Array();
         angular.forEach($scope.categories, function(value,key) {
          if(catId==value.parent){
           experts[key]={id:value.id,name:value.category};
          }
            });
         $scope[model]=experts;
        };
```

```html
<div>
    <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
    <li ng-repeat="user in users">
    <label>Name:</label><input type="text" name="<%user.name%>" />
    <label style="display:inline-block;">Email:</label><input type="text" name="empemail[]" />
    <label style="display:inline-block;">Phone:</label><input type="text" name="empphone[]" />
    {{ Form::label('select category','',array('style'=>'display:inline-block;')) }}
 <select name="empcategories[]" ng-model="<%user.name%>" ng-options="k as v for (k,v) in mainCategories" ng-change="categoryChange(emp1,'<%user.model%>')" ></select>
 {{ Form::label('Expertise','',array('style'=>'display:inline-block;')) }}
 <select  name="empspecialized[]" ng-model="empspecialization" ng-options="k as v.name for (k,v) in <% user.model %>">
 </select> 
 <button ng-click="removeUser(user)">-</button>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Error: [ngModel:nonassign] Expression '<%user%>' is non-assignable. Element:   any suggestions or solutions , am waiting thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution to my posted question. The mistake i did, in this tried to assign value that is not assignable to the select option value as **model** value and i changed this to follwing code works for me.

```
<div>
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
<li ng-repeat="user in users">
<label>Name:</label><input type="text" name="<%user.name%>" />
<label style="display:inline-block;">Email:</label><input type="text" name="empemail[]" />
<label style="display:inline-block;">Phone:</label><input type="text" name="empphone[]" />
{{ Form::label('select category','',array('style'=>'display:inline-block;')) }}
<select name="empcategories[]" ng-model="user.category" ng-options="k as v for (k,v) in mainCategories" ng-change="categoryChange(user.category,'<%user.model%>')" ></select>
{{ Form::label('Expertise','',array('style'=>'display:inline-block;')) }}
<select  name="empspecialized[]" ng-model="empspecialization" ng-options="k as v.name for (k,v) in <% user.model %>">
</select> 
<button ng-click="removeUser(user)">-</button>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The result i required here is i need to pass the currently selected option id , to my calling method so that i can match and produce the sub-categories list. I hope it will help you , 
  thank you